# Grouping and Beaming rules for specific time signatures

Tags: theory, beaming

The question asks to rewrite the notes according to the grouping and beaming rules of the given time signature.

[image]
[image]

The first picture is the question and the second picture is my answer to it. Am I following all the grouping and Beaming rules properly or am I making any mistakes? Please give an explanation If I am making any mistakes

Comment: There are already several questions similar to this. Please read them, and their answers, and you'll find where you're right (or wrong).

Comment: Some other stack exchange sites have bans on "proofreading" questions that simply ask "is anything wrong here." Although we don't have that rule, you'll get much better answers if you can say whether there's anything in particular that you're unsure or concerned about in your work.

Answer (score 0):

**A**
Bar 3: Beam all five notes together, then use a second beam for the four semis.
Bar 5: Beam all four, then use a second for the semis.
**B**
Bar 3: No beams joining notes 3 and 4.
Bar 4: Ditto.
Bar 5: No beams joining notes 4 and 5.
**C**
Bar 4: No beams joining notes 7 and 8: note 8 should be a crotchet.

Beaming can help reveal a bar's subdivisions, which makes the music easier to read. Beams that cross the subdivisions - as yours sometimes do - should be avoided.

I've just noticed that you've asked several such 'homework' questions. Please try to focus on a specific rule or problem.